# Spritekit wont show presented scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, skscene

Im having a problem. When i present a new scene in spritekit (with objective c) It only shows a gray color with node and fps count on the screen.

I have animated the scene in the .sks file so it should not look like this.
The transition when im presenting the new scene also works, but it just wont show the images and background that i animated in the .sks file.

Here is the code on how i do it.

```
//In gameviewcontroller.m

// Creating and configuring the scene.
GameScene *Level1 = [GameScene nodeWithFileNamed:@"GameSceneLevel1"];
Level1.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;



 //  GameScene.m inside touchesbegan

 SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition doorwayWithDuration:4];


        GameScene *Level1 = [GameScene sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
        Level1.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
        [self.view presentScene:Level1 transition:reveal];
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to make a transition to the same scene ? You are going from `GameScene` - > `GameScene` currently.

Comment: No, it was just for testing, how would you it for a different scene :)? I have tried it before

Comment: Checkout my answer (I've made an edit)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have originally loaded scene from **.sks** file and as you said you have some animations there. Later on, (inside `touchesBegan`) you are creating a scene by providing a size (using `sceneWithSize` static method). So the scene is not loaded from from the archive.

To fix the problem, load your scene like you did initially, in the `GameViewController`.

**EDIT:**

To transition between two scenes you have to create two `.sks` files. You can name them like this : MenuScene and GameScene (you already have this one by default). Note that when you create these files you don't have to write an extension (`.sks`) but rather just file name. Then you have to create corresponding `.m` and `.h` files. So create `MenuScene.m` and `MenuScene.h`. `GameScene` `.m` and `.h` files are there by default.

`MenuScene` should be a subclass (not necessarily direct subclass) of an `SKScene`.

Then inside of your view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;

    GameScene *scene = [GameScene nodeWithFileNamed:@"GameScene"];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    scene.size = skView.bounds.size;

    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

Later on in your GameScene's `touchesBegan` method if you want to transition to the `MenuScene`, you should do something like this :

```
MenuScene *nextScene = [MenuScene nodeWithFileNamed:@"MenuScene"];
SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:3];  
[self.view presentScene:nextScene transition:transition];
```

Similarly, to transition back to the `GameScene`, in your MenuScene's `touchesBegan`, do this:

```
GameScene *nextScene = [GameScene nodeWithFileNamed:@"GameScene"];
SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:3];  
[self.view presentScene:nextScene transition:transition];
```

Of course right before each transition you can set scene's scale mode to match the scale mode of the old scene.

From your code,  it looks like you are trying to make a transition to the same scene: `GameScene` -> `GameScene`. That is certainly possible, but are you sure you wanted that ?

If so, just use the code I've provided for MenuScene's `touchesBegan` method.

Comment: Ok, but when i try to do this in the GameViewController inside touches began it just gives me error saying " No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'presentScene:transition:'"

Comment: Will edit my answer to show you how you should transition between scenes.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I will try this out now.

Comment: You sir are the man! I cant believe i havent figured this out on my own! Thank you so much! Wish i could upvote your answer..

Comment: @BCAAStian No problem :) You can always come back and upvote it once you get enoguh reputation. In the meanwhile you can mark it as accepted if it solves your issue.

Comment: @BCAAStian You may find this useful to read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work